# MissingMethodException in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app using Xamarin.Forms. I have a method which returns all properties of a given object as a string.

```
public static string GetAllProperties(this object obj)
{
    return string.Join(" ", obj
                            .GetType()
                            .GetRuntimeProperties()
                            .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(obj)));
}
```

It works fine on iOS and UWP, but throws a `MissingMethodException` on Android when accessing `IsTransient` property of the given object.

```
[0:] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Attempted to access a missing method.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Exception:nIsTransient (int)
  at System.Exception.get_IsTransient () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0004b] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] index, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Fantom.Helpers.Global.GetAllProperties (System.Object obj) [0x00034] in ... 
  at Fantom.ViewModel.SignUpViewModel+<<FirebaseSignUp>b__20_0>d.MoveNext () [0x00340] in ...
```

I tried the following with no luck.

- Cleaning the solution and restarting Visual Studio.
- Changing the .NET framework for the PCL project from 4.5.1 to 4.6 (Project Properties > Library > Targeting > Change...), but even though 4.6 is listed it doesn't let me pick it.
- Making sure the latest version of Xamarin NuGet packages are installed on each platform project.

I don't think it would help diagnose the problem, but I have the following NuGet packages installed in the PCL project.

- Firebase.Xamarin
- Humanizer
- Microsoft.Bcl
- Microsoft.Bcl.Build
- Microsoft.Net.Http
- Newtonsoft.Json
- PCLAppConfig
- PCLStorage
- Rx-Core, Rx-Interfaces, Rx-Linq, Rx-Main, Rx-PlatformServices
- Xamarin Forms

Platform projects only have the Xamarin packages installed.

Comment: What type of build? release or debug?

Comment: @SushiHangover Debug. I haven't tried Release.